# how do you find a file's location?

Tags: filesystem, filemanager

Noob here. OK, I

1. Open the Dash.
2. Type "file". An app appears, called "files", icon looks like ta 2-drawer file cabinet. I click that, the app opens
3. I click the "Search button". I type the file name in the box and hit Enter.
4. The program thinks for a while, then displays a result. Great! the program found the file I was looking for! IT knows where myfile.foo is, BUT I DON'T! IT DOESN'T SAY WHERE IT IS!!!!

How do I find out where it is, please?

I hate to say this, but is there an app that works like Windows Explorer (but doesn't crash every 2 minutes)?

Comment: You move the cursor over the file, right click, select properties and then you should be able to see it under **File location**

Comment: Not quite sure why you've been down-voted for a sensible noob question

Answer (score 2):

yes, this should be easier than that for search results, I agree. There's apparently a lot of work been done on search from within the "Files" app. (aka Nautilus) but that's not out yet.

There's the way suggested by Uri Herrera in the comment (right-click → properties → see the Location bit).

Also, it may be handy to know that you can just **Copy** the file (right-click → Copy) as if you actually wanted a copy of it, and if you press paste somewhere like a text box, you'll actually paste the filepath itself.

So let's say your search threw up a file called **foo.pdf** and you wanted to **view other files in the same folder as it**.

1. Right-click foo.pdf and select Copy.
2. Press Ctrl-L (or if you prefer menus, Go → Location...)
3. Now press Paste (which is Ctrl-V, or right-click and choose Paste) and press Enter.

**The Files app will now open the folder with that file in it, and select the file.**

So if you like keyboard shortcuts like me, you can just select the file, hold Ctrl down and type C L V, let go of Ctrl, press Enter and voilá!